# Windows NLB detect dead IIS?

Tags: iis, nlb

We're running 4 webservers through NLB, however every once in a while a single IIS dies on us (not the Windows, it still works, it's just the IIS returns 503 Service unavailable)

Is it somehow possible to setup NLB to detect this, and stop sending traffic to that particular server ?

Furthermore it'd be preferable if it could notify someone when this happens.

Answer (score 4):

No, NLB cannot do this. But, you can write a script that verifies that IIS is working, and if it is not, send a msg to NLB to unload that node from the cluster.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to some documentation for sending a message to NLB ?

Comment: Yes i do: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783990%28WS.10%29.aspx