# NLB - detect service down

Tags: nlb, windows-nlb

I am trying to work out how to use PowerShell to detect when a load balanced (NLB) Apache service is no longer accepting requests (but the service is still running).

[Windows NLB detect dead IIS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/167281/windows-nlb-detect-dead-iis) thread mentions that there are scripts but the link appears to be very old.

Anybody assist?

Eddie.